# Create table from data with multiple values for each property using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import-from-csv

I have data being read in from a .csv file. I think find the min and max values and save them into a variable with the format like this:

```
min_max = {"a":[1,10],"b":[11,20],"c":[21,30]}
```

Where the first value for each property is the min and the second value is the max. I want to create a table of the min and max values for the data. Since the .csv is dynamic and will not always have the same headers, I cannot use something like min_max.a ect. I need to have the table be dynamic.

**Edit**
I should add in that the min and max values are obtained using the following code. If there is a better way to do this, please enlighten me. I am new to object oriented coding and haven't found another way to find all min and max values for each property within the data file.

```
var data_v2 = [
   {"a":5,"b":480,"c":250,"d":100,"e":220},
   {"a":1,"b":90,"c":50,"d":33,"e":88}
];

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, w], 1),
y = {};
y.max={};
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
return (min_max[d] = d3.extent(data, function(p) { return +p[d]; }));
 }));
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: Exactly, except I cannot figure out how to get it to work with the nested arrays. This is a good example of dealing with nesting (link below), but I cannot find one where it does not have keys for certain values and how to access those values. If it were min_max = {"a":{min:1,max:10}..... It would work. I am not sure how to either deal with the nested array or add in the min and max keys. 

http://bl.ocks.org/nautat/4085017

Comment: Well you generate the data yourself, so you can change the data format to anything you like.

Comment: It needs to be able to work for multiple datasets that do not have the same headers. A button on the website chooses the datafile and then the JS needs to create a table so changing the format of the file is not an option.

Comment: Ok, but even then it sounds to me like it would be a pretty straightforward application of nesting, i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/cc3z0fqj/